# PowerApps canvas patch radio button value to a choice column in dataverse

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

I have a Canvas app and I have radio buttons and dropdown list, I am trying to patch to my dataverse table, where I have one Radio and one choice type columns, I couldn't figure out how to save it.

```
 Patch(myTable, Defaults(myTable), {Title:Textbox1.Text,ProjectType:Radio1.Selected.Value, Country: CountryDrp.Selected.Value})
```

I get this error:

```
They type of this argument 'crb3f_projecttype' does not match the expected type 'OptionSetValue (ProjectType (myTable))'. Found type 'Text'
```

Comment: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-patch-an-option-set-field/td-p/422578

Comment: You need to patch data in table/record format. Or if it is not necessary always go with `text` as the data type for every column in the Dataverse table, to avoid any such data format mismatch.